Is it safe to do "snap install" with sudo
I am a root user on a workstation; I give access to others on this system.
They are requesting me to install:
sudo snap install google-cloud-cli

An experienced friend of mine had earlier suggested to me that installing packages using conda, pip, make install as sudo is not recommended. It may overwrite system binaries or libraries and can make system unstable.
How about the above snap install? Is it safe.

You can use sudo with snap package manager as it is a package manager meant for all Linux distros. Canonical has developed it and give it precedence over apt on Ubuntu.

Debian Snap applications are self-contained, specifically for the reason you mentioned -- to avoid compatibility issues with other applications when sharing packages. That issue is comparable to DLL hell under Microsoft's Windows OS.
This implies you can install a Snap app without likelihood of interfering with other applications. However, you should verify the safety of any application before installing it, particularly those from an outside PPA.
There are some downsides to Snap apps:

Because the app contains all resource files, rather than sharing them, downloads are larger and folders use more space.
The publisher of the app is responsible for updates, and frequently they lag the latest version of the app on which they're based. For example, the latest p7zip is based on 7-Zip v. 16.02, eight years out-of-date. [One can download the current Windows 7-Zip, 24.06 at this writing, and run it in wine, though.]
Snap apps may be slower than the corresponding package version (or even a Windows app running under wine).

